# Does the server save the session of a mobile request?

Tags: android, rest, mobile, authentication

I have a background in web development but I am very new to the mobile world. So, I'm not sure how to proceed with this situation:

- The user login in the app
- The credentials are sent to the server through a POST request.
- If the response is ok, it redirects to the main activity.

Now, I want to know if I have to keep the user's ID or not. I know that when we are using a browser the server saves a "session" so the client doesn't need to send the ID everytime to request data. Is that also true with mobile apps (Android)?

By the way, I'm also responsible for building the REST API but don't have any experience targeting mobile devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big question to answer, and it depends and not sure what server technology you are using.  However I can describe an approach I implemented (.Net background).

**It seems you are writing a mobile app?**

The mobile app would first make an authentication call passing id and password to your login api, over https of course.  Often the url would be something like

> //yourwebsite/Account/Token

Your api would validate the user and if ok, issue a bearer token.

The mobile app needs to remember this token and on subsequent calls pass this in the request header.  That's how the server will know who this is.  You don't need to send the user id and password any more.  And there may be a strong security argument for not storing the user id and password on the mobile device at all.

Now, your server code will validate the token, and you will know who and what the user can do.  The token typically expires, so any mobile client needs to check for this and re-authenticate to get a fresh token.

**But how will the server know this token, who it belongs to?**

In an MVC world for example, there's framework code to help here. There's plenty of MVC template code.  If you happen to be developing .Net api services, see this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

If you are not .Net on the server, I'm sure there will be something else to help you along the same principals.

As for developing RESTful API's, ServiceStack is seriously worth considering.  If too expensive, at least consider their approach and roll your own (especially when it comes to versioning of your api's).

Comment: I have to use PHP on server-side, but the main doubt was answered with the token explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand the case with browsers, therefore your conclusion is flawed. Let me explain: When you log in to a website using a web-browser, a session is saved indeed, but not only on the server. It is saved at the client-side as well. Whenever you send a request from there on to the server, you have to send that stored information as well, called cookie to identify yourself.

Let's think about this more deeply: How would a server identify your session as being your session without getting a cookie? By IP address? Nope, the IP address can be used by many and it might change. By browser session? Yes, by browser session, which includes the cookie as well.

Now that you understand that the session is saved by both the server and the client, you surely already know that you need the very same for mobile apps as well. The client logs in, therefore a cookie is generated for the client. This should be difficult to guess. From there on, the client uses the server using the cookie created for it.

If you do not believe me, visit a website where you are not logged in, and then run `console.log(document.cookie);`, log in, then run `console.log(document.cookie)` again, then log out andd run `console.log(document.cookie)` again.

Comment: Yeah I was unaware of what happens behind the scenes with the browser, so I had no idea that it had to be done _manually_ with the app.